# How to use [(ngModel)] in html helper controls such as @Html.DropDownList

Tags: razor, data-binding, angular7, html-helper

I am using angular 7 and MVC

I need to use [(ngModel)] in html helper controls, I tried the following way

```
 @Html.DropDownList("StateCode", StateList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "StateCode", @name = "StateCode", ng_model =StateCode" })
```

But it doesn't bind the dropdown value. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding as `[(ngModel)]`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StateCode", StateList, new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "class", "form-control" },
        { "id", StateCode },
        { "name", "4" },
        { "[(ngModel)]", "StateCode" }
    })
```